# ERROR: Could not find credentials entry with ID 'null'

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am unable to pass credentials to Jenkins job when I try to `Build with Parameters`. I have written a groovy script where it deploys to different environments. Below is a code snippet where I have written in a switch case:

```
switch (defaults.get('pipelineStrategy')) {
            case 'deployToEnv':
                if (params.deployToDev) {
                    deployToDev(defaults, env)
                }
                else (params.deployToTest) {
                    deployToTest(defaults, env)
                }
                break
}
```

Below is the script for `deployToDev.groovy`

```
void call(Map configuration, env) {

    environment {
        K8S_DEV_NS_TOKEN   = "dev-ns-cicd"
    }

    echo 'Starting deploy only pipeline'
    println("executing deployToDev")
    pipeline {
        agent { label 'docker-kitchensink-slave' }
        stages {
            stage('Checkout') {
                steps{
                    checkout scm
                }
            }
            stage('Deploy to Dev') {
                steps {
                    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "$env.K8S_DEV_NS_TOKEN", variable: 'DEV_TOKEN')]) {
                        kubernetesDeploy(hcEnv: 'dev', hcToken: "${DEV_TOKEN}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below are the Jenkins build logs:

```
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Could not find credentials entry with ID 'null'

Could not update commit status, please check if your scan credentials belong to a member of the organization or a collaborator of the repository and repo:status scope is selected


GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument `env` in `void call(Map configuration, env)` override pipeline reserved global variable: `env`.

Please remove the argument `env` from `call` function.